# How to sum the values of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'd like to sum the values of an object.

I'm used to python where it would just be:

```
sample = { 'a': 1 , 'b': 2 , 'c':3 };
summed =  sum(sample.itervalues())
```

The following code works, but it's a lot of code:

```
function obj_values(object) {
  var results = [];
  for (var property in object)
    results.push(object[property]);
  return results;
}

function list_sum( list ){
  return list.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
      return previousValue + currentValue;
  });
}

function object_values_sum( obj ){
  return list_sum(obj_values(obj));
}

var sample = { a: 1 , b: 2 , c:3 };
var summed =  list_sum(obj_values(a));
var summed =  object_values_sum(a)
```

Am i missing anything obvious, or is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You could put it all in one function:

```js
function sum( obj ) {
  var sum = 0;
  for( var el in obj ) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty( el ) ) {
      sum += parseFloat( obj[el] );
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
    
var sample = { a: 1 , b: 2 , c:3 };
var summed = sum( sample );
console.log( "sum: "+summed );
```

---

For fun's sake here is another implementation using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (browser support should not be a big issue anymore):

```js
function sum(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((sum,key)=>sum+parseFloat(obj[key]||0),0);
}
let sample = { a: 1 , b: 2 , c:3 };

console.log(`sum:${sum(sample)}`);
```

But this seems to be way slower: [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/summing-objects)

Comment: return sum + parseFloat( obj[key] || 0) to check the falsey or null /blank values

Comment: Great job highlighting the performance difference between the solutions. Whilst the `Object.keys().reduce` looks so much more elegant, it is 60% slower.

Comment: niiiiiiiiceeeeeee

Answer (score 179):

It can be as simple as that:

```
const sumValues = obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Quoting MDN:

> The **`Object.values()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

<sub>from [`Object.values()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)</sub>

> The **`reduce()`** method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

<sub>from [`Array.prototype.reduce()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)</sub>

You can use this function like that:

```
sumValues({a: 4, b: 6, c: -5, d: 0}); // gives 5
```

---

Note that this code uses some ECMAScript features which are not supported by some older browsers (like IE). You might need to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code.

Comment: This requires you pull a 60K library *just* to have `Object.values()`, which will be polyfilled with a `for` loop on every browser besides Firefox. Even without a polyfill, it's 4x slower than a regular `for` loop for me.

Comment: @Blender You need to use Babel anyway if you want to use *any* of the new ECMAScript features and still support older browsers. Besides, if someone visits this question for example after 2 years, modern browsers will probably implement `Object.values()` until that time.

Comment: The accepted answer has a very similar approach, but the function passed to `reduce` seems a bit more foolproof. Did you leave out the parsing on purpose?

Comment: @Cerbrus I assumed that all values in that object are numbers.

Comment: @Blender also Node

Comment: @Blender It seems I was right – a year and a half passed, and [`Object.values()` is supported by all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values).

Answer (score 31):

If you're using lodash you can do something like

```
_.sum(_.values({ 'a': 1 , 'b': 2 , 'c':3 }))
```

Comment: I think JS considers the values as strings. so the answer would be like "123" instead of "6". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 29):

Now you can make use of `reduce` function and get the sum.

```js
const object1 = { 'a': 1 , 'b': 2 , 'c':3 }

console.log(Object.values(object1).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

Answer (score 24):

A regular `for` loop is pretty concise:

```
var total = 0;

for (var property in object) {
    total += object[property];
}
```

You might have to add in `object.hasOwnProperty` if you modified the prototype.

Answer (score 15):

Honestly, given our "modern times" I'd go with a functional programming approach whenever possible, like so:

```
const sumValues = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, value) => acc + obj[value], 0);
```

Our accumulator `acc`, starting with a value of 0, is accumulating all looped values of our object. This has the added benefit of not depending on any internal or external variables; it's a constant function so it won't be accidentally overwritten... win for ES2015!

Answer (score 13):

Any reason you're not just using a simple `for...in` loop?

```
var sample = { a: 1 , b: 2 , c:3 };
var summed = 0;

for (var key in sample) {
    summed += sample[key];
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vZhXs/

Answer (score 3):

```js
let prices = {
  "apple": 100,
  "banana": 300,
  "orange": 250
};

let sum = 0;
for (let price of Object.values(prices)) {
  sum += price;
}

alert(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit tardy to the party, however, if you require a more robust and flexible solution then here is my contribution. If you want to sum only a specific property in a nested object/array combo, as well as perform other aggregate methods, then here is a little function I have been using on a React project:

```
var aggregateProperty = function(obj, property, aggregate, shallow, depth) {
    //return aggregated value of a specific property within an object (or array of objects..)

    if ((typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'array') || !property) {
        return;
    }

    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); //an ugly way of copying the data object instead of pointing to its reference (so the original data remains unaffected)
    const validAggregates = [ 'sum', 'min', 'max', 'count' ];
    aggregate = (validAggregates.indexOf(aggregate.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? aggregate.toLowerCase() : 'sum'); //default to sum

    //default to false (if true, only searches (n) levels deep ignoring deeply nested data)
    if (shallow === true) {
        shallow = 2;
    } else if (isNaN(shallow) || shallow < 2) {
        shallow = false;
    }

    if (isNaN(depth)) {
        depth = 1; //how far down the rabbit hole have we travelled?
    }

    var value = ((aggregate == 'min' || aggregate == 'max') ? null : 0);
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }

        var propValue = obj[prop];
        var nested = (typeof propValue === 'object' || typeof propValue === 'array');
        if (nested) {
            //the property is an object or an array

            if (prop == property && aggregate == 'count') {
                value++;
            }

            if (shallow === false || depth < shallow) {
                propValue = aggregateProperty(propValue, property, aggregate, shallow, depth+1); //recursively aggregate nested objects and arrays
            } else {
                continue; //skip this property
            }
        }

        //aggregate the properties value based on the selected aggregation method
        if ((prop == property || nested) && propValue) {
            switch(aggregate) {
                case 'sum':
                    if (!isNaN(propValue)) {
                        value += propValue;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'min':
                    if ((propValue < value) || !value) {
                        value = propValue;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'max':
                    if ((propValue > value) || !value) {
                        value = propValue;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'count':
                    if (propValue) {
                        if (nested) {
                            value += propValue;
                        } else {
                            value++;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

It is recursive, non ES6, and it should work in most semi-modern browsers. You use it like this:

```
const onlineCount = aggregateProperty(this.props.contacts, 'online', 'count');
```

Parameter breakdown:

**obj** = either an object or an array
**property** = the property within the nested objects/arrays you wish to perform the aggregate method on
**aggregate** = the aggregate method (sum, min, max, or count)
**shallow** = can either be set to true/false or a numeric value
**depth** = should be left null or undefined (it is used to track the subsequent recursive callbacks)

Shallow can be used to enhance performance if you know that you will not need to search deeply nested data. For instance if you had the following array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        otherData: { ... },
        valueToBeTotaled: ?
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        otherData: { ... },
        valueToBeTotaled: ?
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        otherData: { ... },
        valueToBeTotaled: ?
    },
    ...
]
```

If you wanted to avoid looping through the otherData property since the value you are going to be aggregating is not nested that deeply, you could set shallow to true.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lodash

```js
 import _ from 'Lodash';
 
 var object_array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}];
 
 return _.sumBy(object_array, 'c')
 
 // return => 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution from @jbabey while trying to solve a similar problem. With a little modification, I got it right. In my case, the object keys are numbers (489) and strings ("489"). Hence to solve this, each key is parse. The following code works:

```
var array = {"nR": 22, "nH": 7, "totB": "2761", "nSR": 16, "htRb": "91981"}
var parskey = 0;
for (var key in array) {
    parskey = parseInt(array[key]);
    sum += parskey;
};
return(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) one liner:

```
import {
 compose, 
 sum,
 values,
} from 'ramda'

export const sumValues = compose(sum, values);
```

Use:
`const summed = sumValues({ 'a': 1 , 'b': 2 , 'c':3 });`

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate object using **in** keyword and can perform any arithmetic operation.

```js
// input
const sample = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
};

// var
let sum = 0;

// object iteration
for (key in sample) {
    //sum
    sum += (+sample[key]);
}
// result
console.log("sum:=>", sum);
```

Comment: Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449326/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449323/1048572) old answer

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use the for..in loop to find the sum.

```
function findSum(obj){
  let sum = 0;
  for(property in obj){
    sum += obj[property];
  }
  return sum;
}


var sample = { a: 1 , b: 2 , c:3 };
console.log(findSum(sample));
```

Answer (score 0):

`function myFunction(a) { return Object.values(a).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur, 0); }`

Comment: Same as [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882868/1048572)

Answer (score -1):

Sum the object key value by parse Integer. Converting string format to integer and summing the values

```js
var obj = {
  pay: 22
};
obj.pay;
console.log(obj.pay);
var x = parseInt(obj.pay);
console.log(x + 20);
```

Answer (score -4):

A simple and clean solution for typescrip:

```
const sample = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };  
const totalSample = Object.values(sample).reduce(
  (total: number, currentElement: number) => total + currentElement
);
console.log(totalSample);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Doesn't work on empty objects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882868/1048572) for how to do it properly

Comment: But in the example presented the object is not empty.

Comment: Well `totalSample = 6` would also give the correct output for that particular example, but still would be a bad answer