# How find sum of all values in object and included objects in array?

Tags: javascript

How find sum of all value in that object? In object included array with another object with value and may be "next" array with similar structure object.

```
{
  value: 4,
  next: [
    {
      value: 3,
      next: [...]
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      next: [...]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum the values of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449295/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need recursion to deal with the arbitrary nesting of your object:

```js
const nestedSum = o => (o.next || []).reduce((acc, o) => acc + nestedSum(o), o.value);

// Demo
const data = {
  value: 4,
  next: [{
      value: 3,
      next: [{value: 5}]
    }, {
      value: 3,
      next: []
    },
  ]
};

console.log(nestedSum(data));
```

Comment: it seem not correct if change next:[] to next: [{value:5}]

Comment: I added that case to the snippet.

Comment: @trincot Can you make me explain how it be with `o.value`? How i see first we check there have array or not, for work with reduce, then we use recursion and then i don't understand with that part `, o.value`  :)

Comment: `o.value` is passed as second argument to `reduce`, so that the sum that is being accumulated via the callback with start with that value (as opposed to starting at 0). We could of course pass 0 instead, and then add `o.value` to the return value of `reduce`, but that is just one extra operation. Better start the sum directly with `o.value`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to sum the values recursively:

```js
const obj = {
  value: 4,
  next: [{
    value: 3,
    next: [{ value: 1 }]
  }, {
    value: 3,
    next: [{ value: 2, next: [] }]
  }]
};

const sum = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => acc + (
    k === 'next'
      ? v.map(sum).reduce((s, x) => s + x, 0)
      : k === 'value' ? v : 0)
  , 0);

console.log(sum(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sum(obj, current = 0) {
   const nextSum = (obj.next || []).reduce((nextSum, obj) => nextSum + sum(obj, current), 0)
   return current + nextSum + obj.value
}

const example = {
  value: 4,
  next: [
    {
      value: 3,
      next: [{
        value: 7
      }]
    },
    {
      value: 3
    }
  ]
}

console.log(sum(example)) // must be 17
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your object is called tree [Tree (data structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).
You can use [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search) approach to [traverse the tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) and gather the sum along the way.

Other answers say you have to go recursively but you can do it iteratively with the breadth-first approach, I show you both approaches down in the code snippet.

I've expanded your data sample adding null values where there is supposedely no next values (you could use any kind of check really).

```js
let data = {
  value: 4,
  next: [
    {
      value: 3,
      next: [
        {
          value: 5,
          next: null
        },
        {
          value: 6,
          next: null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      next: [
        {
          value: 2,
          next: null
        },
        {
          value: 3,
          next: [
            {
              value: 7,
              next: null
            },
            {
              value: 8,
              next: null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// iterative approach
function breadthFirst(node){
  let sum = 0
  let q = [node]

  while(q.length > 0){
    let node = q.pop()
    sum += node.value

    if (node.next !== null) {
      for (let other of node.next){
        q.push(other)
      }
    }
  }

  return sum
}

console.log('breadthFirst sum (iterative):', breadthFirst(data))

// recursive apporach
function depthFirst(node){
  let sum = 0

  function recursion(node){
    sum += node.value

    if (node.next !== null) {
      for (let other of node.next){
        recursion(other)
      }
    }
  }

  recursion(node)

  return sum
}

console.log('depthFirst sum (recursive):', depthFirst(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function and check if the value of a key is a number then add with the variable , else if it is an array like `next` then iterate through it and again call the same function with a new object

```js
let data = {
  value: 4,
  next: [{
      value: 3,
      next: [{
        value: 4
      }, {
        value: 5
      }]
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      next: [{
        value: 2
      }]
    }
  ]
}

let sum = 0;

function findSum(obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[keys] === 'number') {
      sum += obj[keys];
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj[keys]) && obj[keys].length > 0) {
      obj[keys].forEach(function(item) {
        findSum(item)

      })
    }
  }
}

findSum(data);
console.log(sum)
```