# Javascript. Object.values(...).reduce

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain in detail how this piece of code works?

```
const yourAmazingFunction = (salaries) => Object.values(salaries).reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0);
```

specifically this:

```
((acc, el) => acc + el, 0);
```

Here's all the code:

````
const nonEmptySalaries = {
 John: 100,
 Ann: 160,
 Pete: 130
};

const emptySalaries = {};

const yourAmazingFunction = (salaries) => Object.values(salaries).reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0);

const firstResult = yourAmazingFunction(nonEmptySalaries)

const secondResult = yourAmazingFunction(emptySalaries)

console.log(firstResult); // 390
console.log(secondResult); // 0 ```
````

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @RocketHazmat event better link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#sum_all_the_values_of_an_array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum the values of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449295/how-to-sum-the-values-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I have already looked through these resources, but there were still some questions. In any case, the problem has already been resolved, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why close this? This question seems OK as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take all of the values (in this case an array `[100, 160, 130]`)
2. Loop over the array values, setting `acc` to the result of the last call of the callback, or `0` if this is the first call, and `el` to the current element. Basically add together each number (`callback(0, 100)` then `callback(100, 160)` then `callback(260, 130)` to return `390`).

Comment: You're right, but Nik_K is getting someone else to do their homework for them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything became clear. I recently started learning javascript and have some problems with arrays. Thanks again.